# Python-SQL queries with variables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, variables, select

I am having problems when I run a query to return the information of the students, I get this error:

> File "I:\A2\SQLite\Create Table.py", line 140, in searchStudent
>       cur.execute("SELECT Student_ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM School WHERE First_Name IS "+firstName)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Joshua

Here is the code, Joshua was the input for the name.

```
firstName = input("\nWhat is the first name of the student you would like to search for?")

con = sqlite3.connect("School.sql")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Student_ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM School WHERE First_Name IS "+firstName)

print(cur.fetchall())
```

The database has 30 entries, holding the `Student_ID (primary key)`, `First_Name (text)`, `Last_Name (text)`, `Year (integer)`, `Form_Group(text)` and `House(text)`.

The query should return the details of all students with the same first name. This should include their `Student_ID`, `First_Name` and `Last_Name`.

What is causing the error?

Edit: I tried:

```
WHERE First_Name = "+firstName
```

But that brought the same error.

Comment: `WHERE First_Name ="+firstName` insted of IS

Comment: I tried, but it still returns the same error :(

Answer (score 2):

String literals in SQL need to be surrounded with single quotes (`'`), otherwise the database interprets them as object names - and as you've seen, fails when it can't find the column.

```
cur.execute("SELECT Student_ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM School WHERE First_Name = '" + firstName + "'")
```

However, using string concatination like this is a bad practice, and leaves your application open to SQL-injection attacks. You would be advised to use a prepared statement instead:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Student_ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM School WHERE First_Name = ?", firstName)
```

Also, note that comparing values in SQL is done by the `=` operator, not the `is` operator.